# how to serialize multi-level json using jackson in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

This is the response body that is expected out the endpoint /foo/bar.

As you can see, this is nested `json` and hence for each level do I require a `Java object`. what is the efficient way to construct this?. I am using `Spring 4.1` which in turn uses `Jackson` to `serialize` POJOs.

```
{
    "user": {
        "status": {
            "state": "active",
            "message": [
                "registered on 01.10.2015"
            ]
        }
    },
    "features": {
        "xbox": {
            "state": "enabled",
            "message": [
                "foo",
                "bar"
            ]
        },
      "playstation": {
            "state": "disabled",
            "message": [
                "hello ",
                "world"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is something I have thought

```
  @RequestMapping("foo/bar")
    @ResponseBody
    public Result getData(long id){

    Result result = getUserData(id);

    return result;
    }

public class Result {

   private User user;

   private List<Feature> features;

   //getters and setters

}

public class Status {

       private State state;

       private Message messages;

       //getters and setteers
}

public class State {

   private String state;
   //getters and setters
}

public class Message {

     private List<String> messages; 
     //getters and setters

}
```

Similarly for "features" node, I will construct Java POJO for each level of Json object. I am aware of using `objectMapper` and `JsonNode` but wondering if it is possible to effectively construct nested json using java objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Why do you think your current design is not "efficient", assuming it works?

Comment: @kryger: just too many Pojos with just one field.

Comment: I think that your proposal is the cleanest and correct way to do this serialization, because when you serialize this json into POJOs at the end you will have POJOs instead of JsonObjects and you can easily access methods and properties in POJO. This is what i Think .

Answer (score 0):

Classes like `State` could be an enum, if you know for sure there will only be a limited domain of values. And `Message` shouldn't be a separate class- just embed `List<String> message` directly in `Status`.

If you want a more compact representation, you can always provide your own serializer/deserializer classes to customise the translation.

Comment: so for each json node, you cant get away without having a POJO (unless if I use custom serializer).